# How to get the form-data from request body in postman by using the express node js module

Tags: node.js, express, csv

1. Already created a endpoint to get the csv file data.
2. Now, Initialise the request from postman with following data
   [Request sent from postman to endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdS7o.png)
   3.from the above endpoint, attached the csv file data to it.

Trying to access the csv file data with key as "csvFile" and value as "csvFile.csv"
from endpoint like this, request.file or request.body

I'm not getting any data from it, only `undefined` But, i'm expecting the csvFile as key and the data from csv file data from the given file.

Answer (score 1):

Using [csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser).
It can convert CSV into JSON  and works well with 'express'.

##### Express code

Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors');
const csvParser = require('csv-parser');
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/api/v1/users', upload.single('csvFile'), (req, res) => {
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded.' });
    }

    const readableStream = new Readable({
        read() {
            this.push(req.file.buffer);
            this.push(null); // End of stream
        }
    });

    let users = [];

    readableStream
        .pipe(csvParser())
        .on('data', (row) => {
            users.push(row);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
            res.json({ users });
        })
        .on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error processing file' });
        });
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 8080");
});
```

##### Install dependencies

```bash
npm install express milter cors csv-parser stream
```

##### Run Server

```bash
node server.js
```

##### CSV file

Save as 'testUserFeed_5.csv'

Contents

```
username,password
admin,123456
user1,6789
```

##### Call by Postman

POST URL

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users
```

[image: Result]

Comment: is there any possibility to do this without using multer library ?

Comment: The other approach is to use the [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) library for parsing form data, including file uploads.