# Cannot access file \tmp\tmp when trying to upload a excel file in my database

Tags: node.js, express-fileupload

Why do I get this error when I tried to import excel file in database. I'm using `express-fileupload`
`Error: Cannot access file \tmp\tmp-1-1705547228039`

I check the column and it is the same at my database, so I wonder why im getting this error.

this is my postman.
[image]

index.js

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import uploadUserLibrary from "./routes/uploadUserLibrary.js";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());




app.use("/api/uploadLibrary",uploadUserLibrary);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Connected to the backend on port http://localhost:${5000}`);
});
```

router.js

```
import express from "express";
import XLSX from "xlsx";
import * as fs from 'fs';
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
import path from "path";
import { connection } from "../database/db.js";
const router = express.Router();

const uploadOpts = {
  useTempFiles: true,
  tempFileDir: '/tmp/',
};

router.post("/", fileUpload(uploadOpts), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { excel } = req.files;
    if (
      !excel ||
      excel.mimetype !==
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    ) {
      fs.unlinkSync(excel.tempFilePath);
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "File is Invalid!" });
    }

    const workbook = XLSX.readFile(excel.tempFilePath);
    const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);

    const successData = [];
    const failedData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const {
        date,
        fullname,
        affectedUser,
        eventContext,
        component,
        description,
        origin,
        ipAddress,
      } = data[i];

      const sql =
        "insert into userlibrary (date, fullname, affectedUser, eventContext, component, description, origin, ipAddress) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
      const [rows, fieds] = await connection.execute(sql, [
        date,
        fullname,
        affectedUser,
        eventContext,
        component,
        description,
        origin,
        ipAddress,
      ]);

      if(rows.affectedRows){
        successData.push(data[i])
      }else{
        failedData.push(data[i])
      }
    }

    fs.unlinkSync(excel.tempFilePath)
    return res.json({msg:'Ok', data: {successData, failedData}})
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
  }
  x``;
});

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");
});

export default router;
```

**Addition**

I also tried editing the uploadOpts.

```
const uploadOpts = {
  useTempFiles: true,
  tempFileDir: path.join(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname, '../../tmp'),
};
```

But when I do that, I get this error instead.

node:internal/fs/utils:353
throw err;
^

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '\C:\Users\Student\Desktop\library\api\tmp'
```

Comment: You need to use ['multer'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)  and ['stream'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream) library for form-data file upload in express, an example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77792585/how-to-get-the-form-data-from-request-body-in-postman-by-using-the-express-node/77793636#77793636)